# Как организовать обновление картинки из памяти устройства?

Tags: android, память, кэширование

Есть приложение, которое при запуске из Assets записывает файл в память устройства. Оттуда выводится на экран. В приложении действует сервис, который может в любой момент заменить картинку в памяти устройства(имя картинки остается прежним). При этом на экране остается первая картинка. 
Как можно организовать такой алгоритм, чтобы картинка на экране обновилась в соответствии с картинкой из памяти телефона?

Comment: Всё сильно зависит от архитектуры кода. В общем случае - никакой магии. ПО событию обновления данных надо отобразить новую картинку. Сам же код отображения картинки должен уметь брать изначально обновлённые данные для отображения и, если их нет - изначальные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути у вас есть пару вариантов.

1. Это подход, когда вы сохраняете что-то в базу данных и в этот же момент отправляете какое-то событие, чтоб обновить вашу картинку.
2. Второй вариант это реализовать паттерн Наблюдатель. Чтоб ваша база данных сама информировала всех подписчиков об изменениях.

Например если вы используете Room и LiveData, то есть уже готовые решения.
Как это реализовать, вариантов очень много, в зависимости от проекта и инструментов, которые вы используете.